# Is Islam the perfect religion?

Tags: quran, practical-islam, imaan, scientific-proof

1. As the title suggests, do Muslims believe that Islam as a religion
   is perfect?
2. Is the Quran a perfect religious text?
3. And were the actions of Prophet Muhammad perfect(PBUH) perfect as well?
4. Also, if that is the case, how exactly is perfection defined? Does wide
   misinterpretation count as imperfection? Or being impractical
   count as an imperfection? If at all, it is impractical or
   misinterpreted.

Sorry, for clubbing so many questions but they are closely related.

Comment: At first i thought it is too wide question, than after reading ALL of these questions, i got what you are asking, good question.

Comment: Ok,what exactly do you mean by wide misinterpretations and as you asked for evidence so it would be nice if you also quote some evidence supporting your question.

Comment: May be becuase you have asked so many series in one question you could get good answers if you ask them separately I guess

Comment: Isn't Islam/Quran widely misinterpreted? I also said - "If at all it is misinterpreted" so you can simply say that it isn't. What do you mean by evidence supporting my question? I don't assert anything in the question. Assertions require evidence not facts. But I realize that the question asks for belief, so you need not answer on the evidence part, just answer the rest and I will be happy to upvote.

Comment: @servant I have removed the part asking for evidence .

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, Muslims believe that Islam is the perfect religion.

   Allah swt said in the Qur'an, that He perfected the religion.
2. Of course, the Qur'an is perfect as it is the word of Allah, the All-Knowing Creator.
3. Here, I refer to the Shia school of thought:
   Yes, the actions of the Prophet were perfect and everything he said as well, as he acted and spoke by the will of Allah swt.

One hadith of the Prophet, regarding transcribing his sayings, says:

> [...] They said to him: "O Prophet of God, we hear things from you, should we write them down? He said: "Yes, by all means, write them down.  By thy Lord, everything that comes out of my mouth is the truth."
>
> (Ibn Uday, Taqaid al-Ilm, 73)

4. The definition of perfection in regards to the Qur'an is, that it is the unaltered words of Allah swt,  the  truth.
   In regards to the Prophet, perfection means infallibility. He was the perfect role model and example for mankind.

The interpretations  of the holy verses are not perfect as these are mostly done by "normal" human beings, who might be scholars and therefore  learned but nonetheless not perfect.